# In PHP, convertion of data

Tags: php

What should I do to convert hexadecimal to GSM-7 in PHP. I got this link.
But don'tt know how to do this in PHP? http://www.smsmac.com/help/discover/about-sms/gsm7bit/

Answer (score 1):

You can just build an associative array, based on the table from that site. 
The array can have the keys as the hex column, and the values as the characters.

```
<?php

$array = [
    "0×00"  =>  "@",
    "0×01"  =>  "£",
    "0×02"  =>  "$",
    //... need to fill here all the table
];


function hexToGSM($hex,$array)
{

    if(array_key_exists($hex,$array)) return $array[$hex];
    else return null;
}

var_dump(hexToGSM("0×01",$array));
```

Live demo here: https://3v4l.org/fXO5r